# Where is the best place to store layout logic in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my Rails app, I have several controllers that makeup a site for my client. With end users and Admins using virtually all of the controllers.

I have created a partial for including navigation links. My problem is that I don't want them to appear inside of the admin section. The part that makes this tricky is that while the navigation should appear for things like `pages/home`, `/galleries` or `/galleries/5` they should not appear for things like `/pages/new` or  `/galleries/5/edit`.

Up until now I have been adding logic to `application.html.erb`, but things are beginning to get out of hand, there are so many rules in my if statement that I feel dirty about it. Here is an example:

**snippet from application.html.erb**

```
<% unless current_page?('/') or current_page?('/admin') or current_page?({action: :new}) %>
    <%= render "layouts/top_links" %>
<% end %>
```

This is all I have written so far, but it will almost certainly get even longer if I continue this way. So here are my questions:

1. Where should I put the logic for this and how should I call it?
2. Is `current_page?` the best way to lay this out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put such dirty logic into helper to make it cleaner

```
# layouts/application.html.erb
nav_links

# application_helper
def nav_links
  return "" if action_name.in?['new', 'edit'] || controller_path == 'admin'
  render partial: 'layouts/nav'
end
```

Done.

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted.

Comment: My pleasure to be of a bit help.

Answer (score 1):

You could advance with a role based approach, as it is the most widely used method for access control in rails. Indeed, all those if-else loops in `application.html.erb` would be a little bit of code smell anyway.

Check Ryan Bates [CanCan](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan) gem for this purpose.

Comment: I really wish this would work. And it may be what I end up doing anyway. Here is my issue with this approach, though: If an admin visits the site without logging out, I still want the links to appear. The conditions should be based on location, not user. Does that make sense?

Comment: that does, but you have described the problem associated with it yourself. if you can manage it, then there is no problem at all!

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is to make use of `before_filter`, which you can set up in your `ApplicationController`. What you can do

Apply your own flavour to this, but a goofy example might be:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
    before_filter :set_navigation_visibility

    def set_navigation_visibility
        # Your custom logic
    end
```

That method can also be overridden in the subcontrollers if necessary, or modified using the `:only` and `:except` options.

Another possibility is making use of a role-based access-control system. There are many, one such library I have used is [Simple-Navigation](https://github.com/andi/simple-navigation). [A google search for role-based access control for rails](https://www.google.ca/search?q=navigation%20gem&rlz=1C1CHMO_en-gbCA472CA472&oq=navigation%20gem&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l3.3115j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#q=rails%20role%20based%20access%20control) seems to yield a number of results that might be helpful.